# Origin of the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma

Tags: real-analysis, math-history

When and where did Riemann and Lebesgue give the well known [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma)? A "lemma"  is usually used as a stepping stone to a larger result rather than as a statement of interest by itself. Did Riemann and Lebesgue intend to prove a larger result when they gave this work?

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question belongs to  
[History of Science and Mathematics SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: I don't think Riemann was thinking in term of " $C^\infty_c$ is dense in $L^1$", he probably proved it for any piecewise continuous (improper Riemann) integrable function, and that's all.

Comment: see this for an history of Banach spaces / functional analysis : https://books.google.fr/books?id=MMorKHumdZAC&pg=PA127&lpg=PA127&dq=history+of+Lp+space&source=bl&ots=wXU3x2h5Bp&sig=Tafc8Ojy378Gu33vz6xAAbxJ-80&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisyqOWn43NAhVpDZoKHdXMAJYQ6AEIQDAE#v=onepage&q=prenatal&f=false . @JohnMa : I think the answer is Riemann's proof that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{i \omega t} dt$ vanishes as $\omega \to \infty$ whenever $f$ is piecewise continuous and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(t)| dt < \infty$, so this is a math question

Comment: @user1952009 : The question is not asking for the proof, but when and where did the proof was written.

Comment: [and see this for an application](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/mfms/notes_2015-16/03_Riemann_and_zeta.pdf) of Riemann Lebesgue lemma for proving the [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula), and the functional equation for Riemann's zeta $\zeta(s)$ (a major work of Riemann)

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted a response to this question over at [HSM SE](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3869/origin-of-the-riemann-lebesgue-lemma/3874#3874).